# AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'

Tags: python, theano

I am installing theano 0.8.2 on windows 7 64bit with python 3.5. I am getting above error, even if gof module is available inside theano folder. I have installed Mingw and given the path as well.

Any help..

Comment: Edit your question to include the line of your code which causes this error.

Comment: it causes at import theano

Comment: I have the same error